# Check constraint with ISO standard

Tags: t-sql, constraints, iso, sql-server-2019, check-constraints

I'm learning SQL Server and one of my exercise questions is:

"One of the columns in my SQL Server table contains country names. How do I create a check constraint to ensure country names are using ISO standards"

Any idea? Unfortunately no answer key

I found something for Oracle
https://technology.amis.nl/it/querying-iso-country-names-and-codes-from-sql-exposing-standard-domains-based-on-dynamic-internet-retrieval/

and was wondering if something similar exists for SQL Server

Comment: This looks like a job for a foreign key constraint to an ISO country table rather than a check constraint, with the ISO country code rather than name as the FK.

Comment: The exercise question is under check constraints and there is no country table. So I'm guessing it has something to do with getting the data from the ISO website. See: https://technology.amis.nl/it/querying-iso-country-names-and-codes-from-sql-exposing-standard-domains-based-on-dynamic-internet-retrieval/    But this is for Oracle. I'm not sure something like this can be done in MSSQL